# How do you dispel the pinkish "mist" on enemies?

Tags: tales-of-symphonia-dotnw

in *Tales of Symphonia: Dawn of the New World* i have been noticing enemies which get this sort of pinkish mist around them like with Hawke in Altamira and the Vanguard who attacked Mizuho. when they have this mist it seems that despite doing multiple attacks it doesn't register as a combo and the enemy doesn't stagger/get interrupted like they normally do when you attack.

at the moment i am not sure if i am just dispelling it just from constant attacking or whether it's a timed thing but it does disappear and the enemy then recreates it. so i would like to know how to dispel this mist, is it just attacking or is there something more effective i can do? or do i just have to wait it out?